# how to Appoint yml file path

Tags: spring, yaml

I have use springboot to creat a project.
when I make yml file at src/main/resources/config or src/main/resources , I cant set :
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - 'scheduling'
      - 'yml'
in application.yml to appoint file file path, 
and use `@Value("${importance_info.message.notice}")` to get the appointed value from 
src/main/resources/config/application-scheduling.yml

but if I create yml not in the src/main/resources/config or src/main/resources,  I can't get appointted value from it.

when I use `@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:config/sub/sub-scheduling.yml"})`, still can't get appointted.

Please tell me , how to make config or code to get appointed value from yml file in that file.

Comment: Please, improve your spelling and punctation. You can do that by click on the edit link underneath your post.

Comment: Try  `classpath*:sub/sub-scheduling.yml` or `classpath*:config/sub/sub-scheduling.yml`

Comment: sorry , the really exception is this: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'importance_info.message.notice' in value "${importance_info.message.notice}"